# How do I get Nuxt.js to pre-render the full HTML for pages?

Tags: html, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, prerender

I have a basic app (nuxt version 2.12.2) that I made by running `npx create-nuxt-app`, and setting mode to "SPA". When I use `npm run build` or `npm run generate`, it creates an HTML file for each page, but it does not pre-render any of the actual HTML in the page. It only has the JavaScript that loads the single-page application. I want each page to have pre-rendered HTML for SEO reasons. What is the best way to do that?

I'm really surprised I haven't found anything in the Nuxt.js documentation that addresses this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree it's a gap in the documentation, I've also struggled with that. As it turns out `nuxt generate` acts differently with universal and spa modes. If you want your HTML files to be pre-rendered on the server you need **universal** mode.

Comment: Thank you for this, I thought I was going crazy. I'm deploying a website on netlify and I noticed we have consistently better scores on lighthouse with ssr: true even though there's technically no node behind it. When I mean consistently better I mean like 40 points in score difference from ssr:false to ssr:true. I really couldn't wrap my head around why this was happening! Thank you!